# Как исправить ошибку "Следующие приложения используют файлы" при установке vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

я решил снова заняться программированием , скачал заново vs code и при установке получаю вот такую ошибку[image: Моя ошибка] , не знаю , как исправить пересмотрел все возможные решения не помогают, пытался удалить , не выходит выдает другую ошибку ,помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А если нажать "Далее" то что будет?